# C string print "tmp" instead of the actual string inside it

Tags: arrays, c, string, struct, printing

I'm trying to display the contents of the directory, I am adding the directory name to the array of strings and printing it, but instead of printing the array the program prints "tmp".

```
void do_ls(char * dir){
    struct dirent * entry;
    DIR * dp = opendir(dir);
    if(dp == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Can not open directory:%s\n", dir);
        return;
    }
    setLenAndNum(dir);
    char fileNames[totalNumOfFiles][lenOfLongestFile];  //array to store all file names
    int i = 0;  //index to iterate through filenames
    errno = 0;
    while((entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL){
        if(entry == NULL && errno != 0){
            perror("readdir failed");
            exit(errno);
        }
        else{
            if(entry->d_name[0] == '.')
                continue;
            while(i < totalNumOfFiles){
                for(int j=0; j<lenOfLongestFile; j++){
                    fileNames[i][j] = entry->d_name[j];
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    i = 0;
    while(i < totalNumOfFiles){
        printf("%s\n", fileNames[i++]);
    }
    closedir(dp);
}
```

This is the function in question, the variables totalNumOfFiles and lenOfLongestFile are global variables and they work correctly I have tested them.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE]

Comment: `fileNames[i][j] = entry->d_name[j];` should be replaced with something using `strcpy`

Comment: for the first entry your read with `readdir()` you copy `d_name` to all `fileNames[0..totalNumOfFiles-1]`; After that, `i == totalNumOfFiles` and the second name is not copied anymore because the condition `while(i < totalNumOfFiles)` is already false

Comment: does it print tmp *over and over*? Your program sets all the fileNames[i] to the first filename

Comment: "tmp" was in fact a filename being applied to all names, so it's a logical error and I've fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Internal while is weird. Why looping over `i`?  `i` must only be incremented at each successful `readdir`... Actually you fill `filenames` with the same first entry, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what we have here... My comments... well, in the comments ;)

```
void do_ls(char * dir) {
    struct dirent *entry;
    DIR *dp = opendir(dir);
    if (dp == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Can not open directory:%s\n", dir);
        return;
    }
    // I don't know what function below does
    // I assume it sets totalNumOfFiles and lenOfLongestFile;
    setLenAndNum(dir);

    char fileNames[totalNumOfFiles][lenOfLongestFile];  //array to store all file names
    int i = 0;  //index to iterate through filenames

    // You don't have to set errno to zero
    errno = 0;
    while ((entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        // Statement above guarantees that the loop won't be run
        // when entry == NULL, so what for is the if statement below?
        // It's a dead code. get rid of it.
        if (entry == NULL && errno != 0) {
            perror("readdir failed");
            exit(errno);
        } else {
            if(entry->d_name[0] == '.')
                continue;
            // Ok, so here we are with a SINGLE file entry, and with this
            // SINGLE file entry you fill the WHOLE table with it.
            // This is clearly wrong.
            while (i < totalNumOfFiles) {
                // Also, you should use a strcpy function to copy string.
                // It will copy necessary number of bytes and trailing 0.
                for(int j=0; j<lenOfLongestFile; j++){
                    fileNames[i][j] = entry->d_name[j];
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        // So here all rows in the table are filled with the last read
        // file name
    }
    i = 0;
    while(i < totalNumOfFiles){
        printf("%s\n", fileNames[i++]);
    }
    closedir(dp);
}
```

Here is corrected code:

```
void do_ls(char *dir) {
    struct dirent *entry;
    DIR *dp = opendir(dir);
    if (dp == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Can not open directory:%s\n", dir);
        return;
    }
    setLenAndNum(dir);
    char fileNames[totalNumOfFiles][lenOfLongestFile];  //array to store all file names
    int i = 0;  //index to iterate through filenames
    while ((entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
        if (entry->d_name[0] == '.')
            continue;
        strcpy(fileNames[i], entry->d_name);
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i < totalNumOfFiles) {
        printf("%s\n", fileNames[i++]);
    }
    closedir(dp);
}
```